# Can I paralellize this foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, parallel-processing

> *Currently this script takes about 6 minutes to complete.*

---

Here's my snippet:

```
$items = getSomeItems();
$results = array();

foreach ($items as $index => $value) {
    $valueA = getValueA($value); // 2 minute process.
    $valueB = getValueB($value); // 2 minute process.
    $valueC = getValueC($value); // 2 minute process.
    $results[] = array('a' => $valueA, 'b' => $valueB, 'c' => $valueC, )
}

return $results;
```

Is there some way to paralellize this foreach loop? I don't care the order in with the arrays are added to `$results`, I order them in SQL anyways.

Can I do something like?

```
parallel-foreach ($items as $index => $value) {
    $valueA = getValueA($value); // 2 minute process.
    $valueB = getValueB($value); // 2 minute process.
    $valueC = getValueC($value); // 2 minute process.
    $results[] = array('a' => $valueA, 'b' => $valueB, 'c' => $valueC, )
}
```

C# has a similar idea in [Parallel.Foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx). I'm looking for something similar in PHP.

Comment: What is getValueA,B,C..??

Comment: @Gautam3164: Some random MySQL calls, calculations on numbers (in PHP) and returning a single value.

Comment: Can you show us..??may be your query may takes much time

Comment: @Gautam3164: Yes that's exactly the bottleneck. A long running MySQL query. Unfortunately I can't show you the exact queries.

Comment: If $value is not unique would be to get the items in value order and only do the calls when the value of $value changes. Beyond that there is not much I can suggest without looking at what the slow running queries and the actual processing of them is.

Comment: Possible solution here - http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/?q=node/view/254 - .Basically firing off multiple asynchronus process and then awaiting the results.

Comment: @Kickstart: That's one approach that I'll keep in mind, but in this case it won't fit with my use case.